# Regular expressions for XSD datatypes

Tags: regex, validation, xsd

Where can I find regular expressions for the datatypes defined in XSD?

The [XSD specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2) includes regular expressions for the datatypes, however they doesn't seem to be correct. For example, for [`xsd:float`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#nt-floatRep) the suggested regular expression is `(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)([Ee](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?|(\+|-)?INF|NaN`, which, however, matches even strings like "0.this is not a float":

```
var floatRegex = /(\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)([Ee](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?|(\+|-)?INF|NaN/;
floatRegex.test("0.this is not a float"); # returns true
```

Am I missing something from the XSD specification? Is there other source of correct regular expressions for XSD datatypes (e.g., [RegExLib.com](http://regexlib.com/) doesn't have them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to allow anything around, then add `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end *(with grouping)*:

`^( regex )$`

```
var floatRegex = /^((\+|-)?([0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)([Ee](\+|-)?[0-9]+)?|(\+|-)?INF|NaN)$/; 
floatRegex.test("0.this is not a float"); # returns false
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to anchor the regular expressions.

Comment: However, you should change the comment in your code snippet since the regex test returns false with the anchored regex.

Comment: @jindrichm - Sure, thanks... it was copy/paste from your question - now it says *false*